# window.MathJax is undefined?

Tags: html, reactjs, mathjax

Hi i Have a problem with MathJax library. I want to display the mathjax formula on the screen, but when I use window.MathJax I get the error that it is undefined. Here is how I installed the MathJax in my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax = {
          options: {
            renderActions: {
              addMenu: []
            }
          },
        };
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
          tex2jax: {
            inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
            processEscapes: true
          }
        });
    </script>
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-svg.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="application-content">
    </div>
</body>
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
<script type="application/javascript">
    EMBED.default.init();
</script>
</html>
```

And here is the component where I use the library:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MathBlock extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: false,
        };
    }

    render() {
        const text = this.props.block.getText();
        const latexRegex = /\${2}(.*?)\${2}/;
        const hasLatex = latexRegex.test(this.props.block.getText());

        return (
            <div>
                <div
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: hasLatex
              ? window.MathJax.tex2svg(text.replaceAll('$', '')).innerHTML
              : window.MathJax.mathml2svg(text).innerHTML,
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

MathBlock.propTypes = {
    block: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Because the script tag that loads MathJax has the `async` attribute, it may not be loaded when your `EMBED.default.init();` command likely will run before MathJax is loaded, and so before `window.MathJax` has been defined.

You could either remove the `async` attribute (which will mean your page will have to wait for MathJax to load and compile before the rest of the page is processed, slowing down your initial view of the page), or you could put the `EMBED.default.init();` in MathJax's startup `ready()` function so that it is not performed until MathJax is loaded.

You are loading MathJax version 3, but your current configuration seems to be a mix of v2 and v3 configurations, and it is currently being ignored entirely by MathJax.

You could use

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  options: {
    renderActions: {
      addMenu: []
    }
  },
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
    processEscapes: true
  },
  startup: {
    ready() {
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
      EMBED.default.init();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

(a correct v3 configuration) in place of your current configuration script, and see if that avoids the problem.